# How the series is convergent and absolute convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(nx) + \cos(nx)}{n^{3/2}}$$
 I tried to prove convergence by Leibnitz theorem but can't prove absolute convergent please give me some hint about this.

Comment: Is it a series of functions ? Specify the domain .How did  you prove it is convergent? Provide more details

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)}{n^{3/2}}$$? Notice the denominator

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\nf}{\infty}$

If you instead mean

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(\sin(nx)+\cos(nx))}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Then we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\left|\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(\sin(nx)+\cos(nx))}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\left|\frac{\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|$$$$

$$\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\left|\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|+\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\left|\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{2}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

And this last sum can be easily seen to converge because it is bounded above by $2+\int_1^{\nf}\frac{2}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$ which is obviously finite.

If, however, your question is as intended, then the series does not converge in general on the real line. Take, for instance, $x=\pi$. We have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(\sin(n\pi)+\cos(n\pi))}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(-1)^n}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}=-\frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sum_{n=1}^{\nf}1$$

which is obviously divergence (this divergence can be easily seen similarly for all multiples of $\pi$).

In fact, this divergence of the series holds more generally, as, for any nonzero $x$ we can find infinitely many multiples of $x$ that are arbitrarily near a multiple of $\pi$. Near enough that we can guarantee that infinitely many terms of $\frac{|\sin(nx)+\cos(nx)|}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ are at least $\frac{1}{2x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. Then, since for any series, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, s.t. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \nf} |a_n|\neq 0$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\nf} a_n$ diverges, this series must diverge as well.

Comment: Sir how can I build this type of concepts that you have

Comment: @ShivamMishra These types of things are generally taught in a Calculus-II (or equivalent) course. The concepts I use in the first half of the post are specifically the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) and (although not explicitly stated) the [absolute convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Proof_that_any_absolutely_convergent_series_of_complex_numbers_is_convergent). The second half just uses my intuition. I can provide more information if needed.